# SQL Select Query on two tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, c#-3.0

I have following two tables in sql server db.

`Customer` table:

```
CID(PK)
Customer_Name
Region
Product
```

`Server` table:

```
S_NO(PK)
CID(FK)
Server_Name
Environment
```

I want to select `Customer_Name,Region,Product,Server_Name,Environment` from the tables.

My query is

```
SELECT Customer,Region,Product,Server.Server_Name,Server.Environment
FROM Customer INNER JOIN Server ON Customer.C_ID=Server.C_ID;
```

I get my output as:

```
1  AEON  APAC  SCPO  AEPRDCSG1  Production
2  AEON  APAC  SCPO  AEPRDXEN1  Production
```

But my desired output is:

```
1  AEON  APAC  SCPO  AEPRDCSG1  Production
                     AEPRDXEN1  Production
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Tony that you should use the application/display layer to format your data.  But if you want to do it in SQL you can like this:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  Customer,Region,Product,[SERVER].Server_Name,[SERVER].Environment
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer,Region,Product ORDER BY [SERVER].Server_Name,[SERVER].Environment) AS Ord
    FROM    Customer 
            INNER JOIN [SERVER] ON Customer.C_ID=[SERVER].C_ID
)
SELECT  CASE WHEN Ord = 1 THEN Customer END AS Customer
        , CASE WHEN Ord = 1 THEN Region END AS Region
        , CASE WHEN Ord = 1 THEN Product END AS Product
        , Server_Name, Environment
FROM    cte
ORDER BY cte.Customer, cte.Region, cte.Product, Ord;
```

Comment: Won't this break if there is a second customer?

Comment: I don't think so...  in what way?  The Partition clause on the Row_Number function should take care of it.

Comment: It doesn't work correctly with two customers, I've created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efe81a/1) to test the query.

Comment: @KevinSuchlicki - I take it back, your query does work with multiple customers, but only if you remove the `ORDER BY` clause. Updated [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad2ba/2). These sort of issues are exactly why I said not to format data in SQL ;)

Comment: Agreed @Tony - this is a lot of extra work using expensive CPUs (SQL Server licensing isn't cheap) instead of cheaper web servers.

Comment: @Tony Thanks for creating the SQL Fiddle.  I checked it out.  The ORDER BY is actually essential to getting the correct final output, but you need to order by the CTE columns, not by the column aliases that represent the CASE expressions.  My original query worked, but the output columns were not aliased.  I updated my answer to alias the output columns and ORDER BY the CTE columns.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't attempt to format the output in SQL.

A database stores the data, your application/presentation layer displays the data. Do the formatting in the application layer.

Comment: How should i do that in website application.

Comment: That would depend on the libraries you are using in your web application, and as such is too broad a question to answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a fan of doing this type of formatting in SQL, because the result set is not relational.  The definition of a given row depends on the rows next to it -- thus violating the unordered set characteristics of tables and result sets.

That said, you can do this in SQL:

```
SELECT (case when seqnum = 1 then Customer end) as Customer,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then Region end) as Region,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then Product end) as Product,
       Server_Name, Environment
FROM (SELECT Customer, Region, Product, s.Server_Name, s.Environment,
             row_number() over (partition by customer, region, product order by s.server_name) as seqnum
      FROM Customer c INNER JOIN
           Server s 
           ON c.C_ID = s.C_ID
     ) t
ORDER BY Customer, Region, Product, Server_Name;
```

The final `order by` is very important, if you want to be able to interpret the results correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Tony is right, but I see it as a challenge so I'll solve it:

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Customer ELSE '' END AS Customer,
   CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Region   ELSE '' END AS Region,
   CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Product  ELSE '' END AS Product,
   Server.Server_Name,Server.Environment
FROM (
  SELECT Customer,Region,Product,Server.Server_Name,Server.Environment
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer,Region,Product ORDER BY Server.Server_Name) as RN
  FROM Customer 
  INNER JOIN Server ON Customer.C_ID=Server.C_ID;
) sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Well,

I assume that the Server table has two entries of

Customer Name:  "AEON", 
Region : "APAC",
Product: "SCPO"

Therefore you get 2 lines. If you want to get the first line you need to amend your SQL:

```
Select TOP 1 Customer,Region,Product ,Server.Server_Name,Server.Environment from Customer inner join Server on Customer.C_ID=Server.C_ID;
```

Comment: The desired output is to remove repeated information in the first four fields, not to only return one row.